# Check Point SSL Network Extender works in FF, not in Safari, on Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos, safari, vpn

I am using Check Point SSL Network Extender on Mac (Mountain Lion) with Java 7 update 40.

It works, i.e. connects to the VPN server (sometimes) in Firefox, but not in Safari.

I would like to be able to get it to work in Safari as I have to run different versions of FF which means I have to start and stop it (and reconnecting is flaky). Please don't ask why I use early versions of FF...

I have found the java logs, but have not found out why the client (applet) fails in Safari. If anyone else has any experience or advice as to an alternative, it would be appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work in the latest FireFox (26).

I chose Medium Java security setting. Firefox v26 (latest version) connected (after it failed, cleared cache, tried again). First time this has happened.

I reset Java security setting to High, and Firefox v26 still connected.

Hope this can help someone else out!